# Issue when i try to add New Activity in Android Studio, popup New Activity options window is blank/white

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, windows-10

I try to add new Activity in Android Studio with classic method:

New -> Activity -> Blank Activity

and after click, the popup options window (**New Android Activity**) is blank/white!

The version of the Android Studio is 1.4.0, i have try to install the version 1.4.1 and the problem remain!

This issue appeared after format my pc and installed Windows 10. I don't have the same issue with Windows 7 and 8.1 in other devices.

Note: All required SDK components is installed.

How to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long time, i found the solution on my problem. If anyone have the same problem, **the solution is simple**:

**Try to resize the window, with this action the window refreshed and showing the content!**

Answer (score 0):

I think if you're using computer for programming at the present, you shouldn't upgrade to Windows 10. Because of software compatibility.
Try to re-install again, if it can not be solved, Install the older OS version.

Comment: Today i have re-install the Android Studio again (after full uninstall), but the the problem is still here! I want to avoid install the older OS. The issue is very strange, because other developers they tried Android Studio with Windows 10 and is fully compatible! Why do I have this problem?